# Can I integrate Gutenberg Text Editor with Asp.net explicitly like Tinymce?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I have blog developed by using asp.net. In there I used tinymce as a richtext editor. But few days ago I just tried to implement my blog by using wordpress. In there I saw that when we creating a new post it is extremely easy in wordpress. So I thought if I can use that editor in my asp.net instead of tinymce that would be great. I found that new editor names is Gutenberg text editor. So is there any way to integrate it with asp.net

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg is available as part of WordPress 5.0 and later. Gutenberg is being developed on GitHub under the WordPress organization.

I am sharing the GitHub URL: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg you can try the code to develop it under Asp. Net